# VB.Net/WebForms - Binding a list of keyvaluepair to ListView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, webforms

I am trying to bind a New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) to a listView
Currently, I have a code off:

```
Dim TestList As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
For Each key in GetTPDesc (Which is a list of strings)
    TestList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(GetTPDesc.ToString, 0))
Next
For Each ArtFailedPair in Table
    TestAddIndex = ArtFailedPair.Failed
    If TestAddIndex <> 0 Then
        TestList(TestAddIndex -1) = New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(TestList(TestAddIndex -1).Key, TestList(TestAddIndex -1).Value +1)
    End If
Next
```

Excuse me for the long block of code, I know the implementation is dirty, and the reason why I used List of KeyValuePair, was due to the need on Index-Based colletion, which Dictionary did not provide me as I thought it would.
And then I try to bind with:

```
listView.DataSource = TestList
listView.DataBind()
```

And the ItemTemplate has the Eval("key") and Eval("value"), ofcourse. But it gives me an error, it shows me: 
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1[System.String] instead of the GetTPDesc.
And I also think an incorrent integer value, since it seems to be out of whack.
Thanks.

The GetTPDesc:

```
Dim GetTPDesc = (From tpProducts In context.TestResultLim
                 Where tpProducts.Art_no = productNumber
                 Order By tpProducts.TP_no
                 Select tpProducts.TP_desc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the following line:

```
For Each key in GetTPDesc
    TestList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(key, 0))
Next
```

you are adding the query to the list instead of the strings.

Comment: Why ofcourse, gaaah, such a stupid mistake, thank you very much, I guess I must of been out of my head after 8 hours of VB.Net, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all the List(of T) is not instantiated.

```
 Dim TestList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
```

and you have to add key not a GetTPDesc.ToString()

```
TestList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(key, 0))
```

Comment: Sorry, it is instantiated, I just had to manually type everything, and I tried your method, its essentially the same thing, I just changed my ItemTemplate, still the same problems, shows ObjectQuery instead of GetTPDesc, and shows some malfunctioned integer.

Comment: @Reigo Hein: can you post a fragement of GetTpDesc method?

Comment: I think theres problem with the For Each key in GetTPDesc, after that, the list is filled with System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1[System.String],0, when I tryed to debug it with breakpoints, as opposed to the GetTPDesc what does appear to have real values